# View mode as filter for sibling mode?

Tags: views

is there a way to use the filter the results of one view mode using the results of another?

If I have a set of letters of the alphabet and the first view mode returns A, B, D, & K - Can my second view mode be configured to return the entire alphabet except the result of the first mode?

Comment: Can't just cloning the same view & playing with filter solved the issue ?

Comment: I'd like to not have to create a lot of top level views in order to accomplish this.